# How to use aggregate with count but also consider some of the NA values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe - df1. I want to get it to df2 as shown below using R:

```
**df1**
Cust_id Cust_name       Cust_order
1       Andrew          coffee
2       Dillain         burger
3       Alma            coffee
4       Wesney          chips
5       Kiko            chips
NA      NA              fries
NA      NA              milkshake
NA      NA              sandwich
NA      NA              eggs

**df2**
Cust_order  freq
coffee      2
burger      1
chips       2
fries       0
milkshake   0
sandwich    0
eggs        0
```

I have used the aggregate count function to achieve this but it does not give me the result that I want. I want the orders with the NA values to give "0".
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: aggregate/summarise on a subset with `!is.na(df1$Cust_name)`?

Comment: @Wimpel it doesnot give the Null values 0 frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `formula`-notation for `aggregate` to group by `Cust_order` and calculate a statistic on `Cust_id`. In this case, you want to count the non-`NA` values of `Cust_id`, which you can do with `function(x) sum(!is.na(x))`. We have to explicitly tell it to keep the `NA` values using the `na.action` argument.

```
aggregate(Cust_id ~ Cust_order, df1, FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = na.pass)
```

which gives

```
  Cust_order Cust_id
1     burger       1
2      chips       2
3     coffee       2
4       eggs       0
5      fries       0
6  milkshake       0
7   sandwich       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, sum(!is.na(Cust_name)), by = .(Cust_order)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `sum` on the `Cust_id` column. In this case we are also summing the non-NA records, but without the need to set `na.action`.

Wrap the `aggregate` function with `setNames` to set correct column names.

```
setNames(
  aggregate(df1$Cust_id, by = list(df1$Cust_order), FUN = \(x) sum(!is.na(x))), 
  c("Cust_order", "freq")
)

  Cust_order freq
1     burger    1
2      chips    2
3     coffee    2
4       eggs    0
5      fries    0
6  milkshake    0
7   sandwich    0
```